# Changing string values in Java

Tags: java, string, immutability

I have

```
String newStr = "previous"
```

After sometime i want to change my string to `next`. Now can i do

```
newStr=getNewString(); // Say getNewString return `next`
```

Arent strings supposed to be immutable.

Any other way i can achieve this? Thanks.

**Edit** : Take `neww` instead of `new`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Arent strings supposed to be immutable.

String are immutable.

References to String don't have to be immutable.

```
String s = "hello";
s = "World"; // the reference s changes, not the String.

final String t = "Hi"; // immutable reference
t = "there"; // won't compile.

// immutable reference to a mutable object.
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hi"); // changes the StringBuilder but not the reference to it.
sb = null; // won't compile.
```

Comment: Doubt! String s="hello" ;  what do i need to do to this string so that it wont compile. If s="world" is going to work after that, how does it happen?

Basically, String are immutable.

References to String don't have to be immutable.

Can you explain this in detail. And will my changing of String s from hello to world cause any problem, memory wise or any other way. Can i use it safely. Thanks.

Comment: as in if i change it from hello to world, the "hello" string does not keep floating in space right? it gets collected by the garbage collector or something, and does it slow down my process. 
What can be the fastest and memory efficient way to change my string from hello to world. Given that i have to do this pretty often.

Comment: I assume you have got the difference between a reference to a String and an actual String object.  I wouldn't worry about space or performance unless you know there is a problem. String literals are not cleaned up until after the class is unloaded (often this is never) "Pretty often" is often not so often that you need to worry about it. e.g. unless you are talking about more than 10 million times every second. ;)

Comment: A key point; when you see `String s`, s is NOT a String. s is a reference to a String, like a `String *s` in C++.  Why doesn't it have the `*`? because there is only references to objects (and primitives) so it would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

String is immutable.Your are changing only the String reference.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are immutable.
What you are changing is a reference to a string, not the string itself.